# The meaning of node of minimax

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am making an AI of dots and boxes and I am implementing the algorithm minimax. But I am confused with the meaning of a new node in tree search. Suppose a node B is the child of node A(ai's turn), so node B is:

1. AI make a move (draw a line between two dots), or
2. AI make moves until it become the manPlayer's turn.

Answer (score 1):

If your child node is the same player's, you need to maximize the score. If it belongs to the other player, you need to minimize the other player's score. As the possible sequences of one player's moves are best searched with the same recursive approach, it may make sense to handle both cases in your minimax method. Alternatively, you may leave the minimax pattern untouched and have another function to iterate over all possible sequences of one player's moves.